# Accessing my forntend running on minikube-linux from chrome

Tags: minikube

I deployed my private frontend applicaiton on minikube, and added a service - all on a linux/debian server.

I'd like to access my app from my laptop browser.
I read that in order to do that I need minikube tunnel.

still I cannot access my app from the browser.

Perhaps I am doing something wrong...?

Here are the details:

```
$ minikube status
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured

$ kubectl get pod
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
oct-frontend-95d76dddc-ghd9m   1/1     Running   1 (18h ago)   3d23h


$ kubectl get deployment
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
oct-frontend   1/1     1            1           3d23h

$ kubectl get service
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
fe-service        LoadBalancer   10.97.182.173    10.97.182.173   90:32224/TCP     127m
kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>          443/TCP          6d2h

$cat fe-service.yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: fe-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 90
      targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app: oct-frontend
  type: LoadBalancer



$ cat fe-deployment.yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: oct-frontend
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: oct-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: oct-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: oct-frontend
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      securityContext: {}
      containers:
        - resources: {}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          name: octopus-fe
          command:
            - /./docker-entrypoint.sh
          env:
            - name: DUMMY_HOST
              value: 10.103.19.196
            - name: DUMMY_BACKEND_PORT
              value: '8008'
            - name: DUMMY_ASSET_MANAGEMENT_PORT
              value: '0000'
            - name: DUMMY_SIMULATOR_PORT
              value: '0000'
            - name: DUMMY_LOCATION_PORT
              value: '0000'
            - name: DUMMY_BACKENDS
              value: 10.103.19.196
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
            - containerPort: 9091
            - containerPort: 9008
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cert-mount
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/ssl
            - name: conf-mount
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/conf
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          image: >-
             cicd.ea.mot-solutions.com:5050/oct/ui-oct4net/oct_fe_imod-provisioning:164
      volumes:
        - name: cert-mount
          secret:
            secretName: oct-fe-2
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: conf-mount
          configMap:
            name: fe-nginx-config
            defaultMode: 420
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600

$ minikube tunnel
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 216101
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 172.17.0.3
        minikube: Running
        services: [frontend-service]
    errors:
                minikube: no errors
                router: no errors
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors
Status:
        machine: minikube
        pid: 216101
        route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 172.17.0.3
        minikube: Running
        services: [frontend-service]
    errors:
                minikube: no errors
                router: no errors
                loadbalancer emulator: no errors
```

Comment: While accessing the application through the browser Is it showing any errors or Page.  If yes can you provide the details

Answer (score 0):

I used port-forward in order to access my app from the browser. From my linux server running minikube:

kubectl port-forward --address localhost, deployment/oct-frontend 9090

where "host ip" is the ip of my linux server running minikube.